# Biscuits with Egg and Butter - how long will they keep?

Tags: food-safety

I have a biscuit/cookie recipe that involves egg and butter - after I bake the cookies how long will they keep, at room temperature in an air-tight container?

(edit: In the USA cookies are (sometimes?) made with egg, is that right? In which case I'm just asking how long cookies keep)

edit: If context helps: my daughter has epilepsy and is on a medically supervised ketogenic diet. What she eats has to be carefully made and carefully rationed. I'm making her a batch of biscuits based on [this recipe](https://www.matthewsfriends.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/Biscuits-using-Psyllium-Husk.pdf) and so I'm wondering how big a batch I can make in one go based on how long they will keep. I imagine all the ingredients are pretty long lasting except for the eggs and butter.

Comment: I've never personally had cookies in a tin last long enough to go bad...

Comment: I am surprised, but I can't find an existing canonical answer about the shelf life of baked goods!

Comment: Can you also be specific on "room temperature" and what's the local humidity? The industry in general understands it as being between 20-25C and punctual excursions to the range of 15-30C which might not be the case in many locations

Comment: @JulianaKarasawaSouza Happy to go with the industry standard

Comment: There are many different ways to make cookies, with and without eggs; you cannot really generalize that cooking made in the USA have eggs or not.-

Comment: The egg and butter are cooked into the product, and won't behave like raw egg and butter.  If you want to preserve them for a long time, use the freezer.  If you want a few hours in a lunch box, I doubt there's a problem.  (E.g. I never had any problem taking egg sandwiches for my lunch, and most people put butter on their sandwiches without thinking about it.)

Comment: @Johanna should I interpret that as meaning they last a long time? (and did they have egg in them?) ... or should I interpret as meaning they get eaten very quickly? : )

Comment: the recipe you put looks just weird, are the quantities in grams ?

Comment: @codeulike I'm asking what are the conditions in your location, since I don't know where you're writing this from. Depending on the place, meeting room temperature standards might imply air conditioning

Comment: @Max yes its in grams. Its very precise because the aim is to get a Fat to (Carbs+Protein) ratio of 3:1

Comment: Hi @JulianaKarasawaSouza I'm in the UK so room temperature is roughly what you describe for the industry standard. Humidity in the UK is roughly 70% I think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically once cooked and if stored in a dry container cookies will keep for a couple of weeks at room temperature and several months (perhaps a year) in the freezer.

The biggest problem with these cookies will be degradation of the fats in the almonds and butter resulting in rancid tastes - these are not dangerous, just unpleasant.

There are few risks with food safety regarding cooked cookies as the temperature of cooking is enough to kill all potential pathogens and typically lowers the [water activity](https://www.metergroup.com/food/articles/water-activity-snack-foods/) within the cookie to a point where few pathogens are capable of growing. It is hard to say what the exact water activity of your cookies will be, but I suspect fairly low.

Comment: To add a few figures on that, the recipe has not much in terms of water content, and considering that OP is sitting in the UK, they'll last for about 2 weeks in a dry, airtight container (to avoid rancid tast)